# How do I add query parameter to CSS and JS files in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, deployment, build

**Scenario**

I use CDN to cache HTML pages and other static files. When I have a new deployment, *CDN takes around 15minute to clear cache globally*, CDN might response HTML page from cache, but CSS and JS cache might hit the origin, due to cache invalidation or cachetimeout. On this use case, those static files are not found on the server because of the new deployment.

My aim is to append build-id/deployment-id as a query parameter. Therefore, application load balancer routes the traffic to right folder where I host static files separately different folder based on build-id/deployment-id. So, I avoid the scenario above.

**Question**

As I stated on the title, how do I add a query parameter, which is build-id, to static files, such as CSS and JS?

On build time, nextjs hashes CSS and JS files and I don't know what piece of code is responsible for hashing. So, I didn't try anything.

I've seen **dpl** query parameter, see the code below, in the HTML page source in nextjs.org. It must be possible, but I don't know how.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/6514b5221347ce7f.css?dpl=dpl_6JFoyTSy77iLYSepen2QrbBEzoPV" data-precedence="next"/>

<link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/chunks/webpack-1e5221d51f7346e8.js?dpl=dpl_6JFoyTSy77iLYSepen2QrbBEzoPV" as="script" fetchPriority="low"/>
```